# Problems with vue in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to implement
[Media manager 3.6.7](https://github.com/ctf0/Laravel-Media-Manager/tree/v3.6.7) to my laravel 5.8 project but i am facing problems with VUE. (This is my first time using it).

In console it gave me two errors: [Error in console](https://prnt.sc/1010741) with BLANK page but when i click on page source i can see that the page is rendered: [Page source](https://pastebin.com/N9Wxw6Q0)

I think I am stuck at this:

```
// app.js
window.Vue = require('vue')
require('../assets/vendor/MediaManager/js/manager')
new Vue({
    el: '#app'
})
```

Where should i put it ? If I put it in media.blade.php i got Require is not a function. If i include require, there is another error
`Module name "vue" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])`

If i use require(['vue']) i got like, 20 errors..

What is the problem here? Previous steps are completed succesffully.

Comment: The error is that you have not registered the component, which means first you need to import it and then you need to define it in the components section inside the script tag.
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Local-Registration

Comment: Since i am new to this, can you explain my  how it should look in my app.js ?

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly says that you have not registered the component properly.

In app.js file:

```
import ComponentA from '/*path of the file*/'
import ComponentB from '/*path of the file*/'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'my-notification': ComponentA,
    'media-manager': ComponentB
  }
})
```

Comment: /*path of the file*/ What is this for? Path to which file ?

Comment: The file in which you have defined the component `my-notification`.
Where the my-notification is coming from?

Comment: From the same file where i am trying to add the code. This is the file: https://pastebin.com/9K2XjWXH

Comment: Somewhere you have defined the `my-notification` component with an extension .vue or it's coming from an external package.

Comment: use relative path which starts with '@'. Thus your path will be resolved and your IDE will help you to do that

Comment: I can't find my-notification.vue on entire project. But the second one i found. File name is manager.vue. I've added `import MediaManager from '/resources/assets/vendor/MediaManager/js/components/manager.vue'` and deleted my-notification and i can see one more error now. media:1510 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module